# Is it possible to do concatenation purely inside a HTML tag parameter?

Tags: html, tags, concatenation

For example:

```
<img src="http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support." + "png">
```

When it executes the img src tag will only read the **http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support.** but not the **png**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

You probably just want a real link with an image inside:

```
<a href="http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support">
    <img src="http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support.png"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably concatenating image's type with the link to image in html wont work. But the only easiest thing here would be this way.
I believe there is no necessity to concatenate the way you have asked for

```
 <a href="your-link">
 <img src="http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support.png" alt="text"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to use concatenation in html. There's no such variable to concatenate. What you need is to load the image inside that page but not to point to the image path.

So, when user enters this url or go through the link:

```
http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/help-and-support
```

There you can load image or background image html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
<img src="http://www.pfpenergy.co.uk/media/1184/help-and-support.png"
 alt="help and support" />
...
</html>
```

Comment: The reason why I want to do this way is for Salesforce purposes. Please see this my original question intent here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/196397/38191

Comment: That's not the url but image path. You can call such defining in another file and including that file in your email html template but not directly on that template.